# Connecting to wifi wlan0 via command line

Tags: command-line, wireless, scripts

I am writing a script where I would like to connect to the wifi from the script.
The below command fails for me:

`printf '%s\n' "$WIFIPASSPHRASE" | iwctl station wlan0 connect $WIFINETWORK`

When I execute the script I get the below in my terminal output:

`Type the network passphrase for _MYWIFI_ psk.`

`Passphrase: _my passphrase will be printed_`

`Operation aborted`

Any idea how to fix this or a better way of achieving this?

Comment: The version of Ubuntu you are using is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me thank you. I was not aware of the --passphrase option.

`iwctl --passphrase $WIFIPASSPHRASE station device connect $WIFINETWORK`

May be piping the passphrase is not allowed.